# Convert unstructured csv file to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am learning R for text mining. I have a TV program schedule in form of CSV. The programs usually start at 06:00 AM and goes on until 05:00 AM the next day which is called a broadcast day. For example: the programs for 15/11/2015 start at 06:00 AM and ends at 05:00 AM the next day.

Here is a sample code showing how the schedule looks like:

```
 read.table(textConnection("Sunday|\n 01-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|\nMonday|\n 02-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|"), header = F, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

whose output is as follows:

```
  V1|V2
Sunday |  
01-Nov-15 |       
6 | Tom  
some information about the program |       
23.3 |  Jerry  
some information about the program |       
5 | Avatar  
some information about the program |       
5.3 | Panda  
some information about the program |       
Monday  |       
02-Nov-15|       
6  Jerry  
some information about the program |      
6.25 | Panda  
some information about the program |      
23.3 | Avatar  
some information about the program |       
7.25 |   Tom  
some information about the program |
```

I want to convert the above data into a form of data.frame

```
Date            |Program|Synopsis
2015-11-1 06:00 |Tom    | some information about the program
2015-11-1 23:30 |Jerry  | some information about the program
2015-11-2 05:00 |Avatar | some information about the program
2015-11-2 05:30 |Panda  | some information about the program
2015-11-2 06:00 |Jerry  | some information about the program
2015-11-2 06:25 |Panda  | some information about the program
2015-11-2 23:30 |Avatar | some information about the program
2015-11-3 07:25 |Tom    | some information about the program
```

I am thankful for any suggestions/tips regarding functions or packages I should have a look at.

Comment: @akrun no, its a simple csv file.I just added '|' to show the separation of columns.

Comment: Thanks for the message.  Looks like you already got a solution.  So, I am not trying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a mess, but it seems to work:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(txt <- "Sunday|\n 01-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|\nMonday|\n 02-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|"), header = F, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = F)
cat(txt)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") # if needed
weekdays <- format(seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+6, 1), "%A")
days <- split(df, cumsum(df$V1 %in% weekdays))
lapply(days, function(dayDF) {
  tmp <- cbind.data.frame(V1=dayDF[2, 1], do.call(rbind, split(unlist(dayDF[-c(1:2), ]), cumsum(!dayDF[-(1:2), 2]==""))), stringsAsFactors = F)
  tmp[, 1] <- as.Date(tmp[, 1], "%d-%B-%y")
  tmp[, 2] <- as.numeric(tmp[, 2])
  tmp[, 5] <- NULL
  idx <- c(FALSE, diff(tmp[, 2])<0)
  tmp[idx, 1] <- tmp[idx, 1] + 1
  return(tmp)
}) -> days
days <- transform(do.call(rbind.data.frame, days), V1=as.POSIXct(paste(V1, sprintf("%.2f", V11)), format="%Y-%m-%d %H.%M"), V11=NULL)  
names(days) <- c("Date", "Synopsis", "Program")
rownames(days) <- NULL
days[, c(1, 3, 2)]
#                  Date Program                            Synopsis
# 1 2015-11-01 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
# 2 2015-11-01 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
# 3 2015-11-02 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
# 4 2015-11-02 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
# 5 2015-11-02 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
# 6 2015-11-03 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, as mentioned earlier in the post, the broadcast day contains also contains programs of next day until 5 AM.

Comment: You're welcome. Where`s the broadcast day in your example?

Comment: The "Date" column in the solution contains different date and time. As shown n my example, the schedule for 01 Nov contains programs for  02 Nov as well until 05:00 AM.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(splitstackshape)

txt <- textConnection("Sunday|\n 01-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|\nMonday|\n 02-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|")
tv <- readLines(txt)
DT <- data.table(tv)[, tv := gsub('[|]$', '', tv)]

wd <- levels(weekdays(1:7, abbreviate = FALSE))

DT <- DT[, temp := tv %chin% wd
         ][, day := tv[temp], by = 1:nrow(tvDT)
           ][, day := na.locf(day)
             ][, temp := NULL
               ][, idx := rleid(day)
                 ][, date := tv[2], by = idx
                   ][, .SD[-c(1,2)], by = idx]

DT <- cSplit(DT, sep="|", "tv", "long")[, lbl := rep(c("Time","Program","Info")), by = idx]
DT <- dcast(DT, idx + day + date + rowid(lbl) ~ lbl, value.var = "tv")[, lbl := NULL]

DT <- DT[, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(date), sprintf("%01.2f",as.numeric(as.character(Time)))), format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M")
   ][, datetime := datetime + (+(datetime < shift(datetime, fill=datetime[1]) & datetime < 6) * 24 * 60 * 60)
     ][, .(datetime, Program, Info)]
```

The result:

```
> DT
              datetime Program                               Info
1: 2015-11-01 06:00:00     Tom some information about the program
2: 2015-11-01 23:30:00   Jerry some information about the program
3: 2015-11-02 05:00:00  Avatar some information about the program
4: 2015-11-02 06:00:00     Tom some information about the program
5: 2015-11-02 23:30:00   Jerry some information about the program
6: 2015-11-03 05:00:00  Avatar some information about the program
```

---

***Explanation:***

**1:** read data, convert to a *data.table* & remove trailing `|`:

```
txt <- textConnection("Sunday|\n 01-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|\nMonday|\n 02-Nov-15|\n 6|Tom\n some information about the program|\n 23.3|Jerry\n some information about the program|\n 5|Avatar\n some information about the program|")
tv <- readLines(txt)
DT <- data.table(tv)[, tv := gsub('[|]$', '', tv)]
```

**2:** extract the weekdays into a new column

```
wd <- levels(weekdays(1:7, abbreviate = FALSE)) # a vector with the full weekdays
DT[, temp := tv %chin% wd
   ][, day := tv[temp], by = 1:nrow(tvDT)
     ][, day := na.locf(day)
       ][, temp := NULL]
```

**3:** create an index per day & create a column with the dates

```
DT[, idx := rleid(day)][, date := tv[2], by = idx]
```

**4:** remove unnecessary lines

```
DT <- DT[, .SD[-c(1,2)], by = idx]
```

**5:** split the time and the program-name into separate rows & create a label column

```
DT <- cSplit(DT, sep="|", "tv", "long")[, lbl := rep(c("Time","Program","Info")), by = idx]
```

**6:** reshape into wide format using the 'rowid' function from the development version of data.table

```
DT <- dcast(DT, idx + day + date + rowid(idx2) ~ idx2, value.var = "tv")[, idx2 := NULL]
```

**7:** create a dattime column & set the late night time to the next day

```
DT[, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(date), sprintf("%01.2f",as.numeric(as.character(Time)))), format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M")
   ][, datetime := datetime + (+(datetime < shift(datetime, fill=datetime[1]) & datetime < 6) * 24 * 60 * 60)]
```

**8:** keep the needed columns

```
DT <- DT[, .(datetime, Program, Info)]
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** This sets up some functions and then consists of four `transform(...) %>% subset(...)` code fragments linked together using a magrittr pipeline. We assume `DF` is the output of the `read.table` in the question.

First, load the zoo package so get access to `na.locf`.   Define a `Lead` function which shifts each element by 1 position.  Also define a `datetime` function which converts a date plus a h.m number to a datetime.

Now convert the dates to `"Date"` class.  The rows that are not dates will become NA.  Use `Lead` to shift that vector by 1 position and then extract the NA positions effectively removing the weekday rows.    Now use `na.locf` to fill in the dates and keep only rows with duplicated dates effectively removing the rows  containing only a date.  Next set `Program` as `V1` and `Synopsis` as `V2` except we must shift `V2` using `Lead` since the `Synopsis` is on the second row of each pair.  Keep only the odd positioned rows.  Produce `datetime` and pick out desired columns.

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo) # needed for na.locf

Lead <- function(x, fill = NA) c(x[-1], fill)  # shift down and fill
datetime <- function(date, time) {
              time <- as.numeric(time)
              as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s %.0f:%02f", date, time, 100 * (time %% 1))) + 
                      24 * 60 * 60 * (time < 6) # add day if time < 6
}

DF %>% 

   transform(date = as.Date(V1, "%d-%b-%y")) %>% 
   subset(Lead(is.na(date), TRUE)) %>%   # rm weekday rows

   transform(date = na.locf(date)) %>%  # fill in dates
   subset(duplicated(date)) %>% # rm date rows

   transform(Program = V2, Synopsis = Lead(V1)) %>% 
   subset(c(TRUE, FALSE)) %>%  # keep odd positioned rows only

   transform(Date = datetime(date, V1)) %>% 
   subset(select = c("Date", "Program", "Synopsis"))
```

giving:

```
                 Date Program                            Synopsis
1 2015-11-01 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
2 2015-11-01 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
3 2015-11-02 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
4 2015-11-02 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
5 2015-11-02 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
6 2015-11-03 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
```

**2) dplyr** and here it is using dplyr and the `datetime` function above.  We could have replaced the `transform` and `subset` functions in (1) with dplyr `mutate` and `filter` and `Lead` with `lead` but for variety we do it another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) # na.locf

DF %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(V1, "%d-%b-%t")) %>%
   filter(lead(is.na(date), default = TRUE)) %>% # rm weekday rows
   mutate(date = na.locf(date)) %>% # fill in dates
   group_by(date) %>%
   mutate(Program = V2, Synopsis = lead(V1)) %>%
   slice(seq(2, n(), by = 2)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(Date = datetime(date, V1)) %>%
   select(Date, Program, Synopsis)
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

                 Date Program                            Synopsis
               (time)   (chr)                               (chr)
1 2015-11-01 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
2 2015-11-01 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
3 2015-11-02 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
4 2015-11-02 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
5 2015-11-02 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
6 2015-11-03 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
```

**3) data.table**  This also uses `na.locf` from zoo and `datetime` defined in (1):

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dt <- data.table(DF)
dt <- dt[, date := as.Date(V1, "%d-%b-%y")][
          shift(is.na(date), type = "lead", fill = TRUE)][, # rm weekday rows
          date := na.locf(date)][duplicated(date)][,  # fill in dates & rm date rows
          Synopsis := shift(V1, type = "lead")][seq(1, .N, 2)][, # align Synopsis
          c("Date", "Program") := list(datetime(date, V1), V2)][, 
          list(Date, Program, Synopsis)]
```

giving:

```
> dt
                  Date Program                            Synopsis
1: 2015-11-01 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
2: 2015-11-01 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
3: 2015-11-02 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
4: 2015-11-02 06:00:00     Tom  some information about the program
5: 2015-11-02 23:30:00   Jerry  some information about the program
6: 2015-11-03 05:00:00  Avatar  some information about the program
```

**UPDATE:**  Simplified (1) and added (2) and (3).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation and code. The date on the 3rd row should be 2 Nov and the date on 6th row should be 3rd  Nov, like mentioned in my example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain how you fixed it. Sorry for being naive.

Comment: Have simplified (1) and added dplyr solution (2).